# Enable logging in SpringMVC, not using Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating a simple SpringMVC project，and want to logging all incoming requests, include uri/query/payload/clientIp... , all info.

All resources I can find are about Spring Bootfor example:
https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring/log-incoming-requests-spring/

I also read the official docs and found `enableLoggingRequestDetails` option, but there's no detail about it, I tried and not working.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-logging

So, how to implement this in pure SpringMVC framework (without Spring Boot)?

Is there a SpringMVC built-in approach to do it?

Answer (score 2):

**1.** You can **implement a Filter** class extending from [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) and then every request will go through you filter. Then you can log what you want inside this class.

```
    @Slf4j
    @Component
    public class RequestLoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            log.debug(
                    String.format("FILTERED URL: %s", request.getRequestURI())
            );

            //continue filtering
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

**2.** Another way is to **implement an Interceptor** class extending from [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html).

```
    @Slf4j
    @Component
    public class RequestLoggingHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            log.debug(
                    String.format("HANDLER(pre) URL: %s", request.getRequestURI())
            );

            return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
            log.debug(
                    String.format("HANDLER(post) URL: %s", request.getRequestURI())
            );

            super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
        }
    }
```

But you have to enable this interceptor by adding it via configuration explicitly.

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebApplicationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Setter(onMethod_ = @Autowired)
        private RequestLoggingHandler requestLogger;

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(requestLogger);
        }
    }
```

**3.** One more way is to use standard **CommonsRequestLoggingFilter**.

This way you should configure it with configuration like:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
          = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

And then enable it into logback.xml:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Java, can u explain what a 'logback.xml' is? I don't have this file in may project.

Comment: @guojiubo `logback-spring.xml` - is the settings file for logger used by SpringBoot. You may check out an example in official Spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Comment: @guojiubo check out my post, i have updated it with examples.

Comment: Thank u, but i'm not using SpringBoot right now, currently i'm trying to use SpringMVC only, some day i will try it.

Comment: @guojiubo you can use it all in spring without any changes if you enable annotation processing in application-context.xml. Or you may instantiate these beans right into application-context.xml.

Comment: Could you filter out some exceptions in you Filter?

Answer (score 0):

Well in order to enable logging in Spring Application all you need is

Log library and its property file

> To make Log4j work with the default JCL dependency (commons-logging)
>   all you need to do is put Log4j on the classpath, and provide it with
>   a configuration file (log4j.properties or log4j.xml in the root of the
>   classpath).

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
```

Refer [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e826) and sample [project](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/)

Comment: Very helpful, I followed your instruction and see a log now: "17:37:50,264 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-4 support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'homeController'". But how can i logging incoming requests's info, like URI, query...etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Interceptor** you can achieve this one.Check below links,you will get an idea

[enter link description here](https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-4-how-to-intercept-request-with-a-handlerinterceptor)

[spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor)

[spring-mvc-4-how-to-intercept-request-with-a-handlerinterceptor](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/)

**Edit:**

Using **CommonsRequestLoggingFilter**

> Spring MVC provides CommonsRequestLoggingFilter which can log request URL, body and other related information.

[CommonsRequestLoggingFilter](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=enadim/spring-cloud-ribbon-extensions/spring-cloud-ribbon-extensions-master/src/main/java/com/github/enadim/spring/cloud/ribbon/support/HttpLoggingConfig.java)

**LoggingConfig.java**

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:logging.properties")
public class LoggingConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(env.getProperty("logging.client"));
        loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(env.getProperty("logging.query"));
        loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(env.getProperty("logging.payload"));
        loggingFilter.setIncludeHeaders(env.getProperty("logging.headers"));
        return loggingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter springLogging() {
        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.class);
                logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        return requestLoggingFilter();
    }
}
```

**logging.properties**

```
logging.client = true
logging.query = true
logging.payload = true
logging.headers = true
```

Comment: Thanks, i believe Interceptor can achieve the goal, but i'm looking for a SpringMVC built-in approach to do it, can u help me?